# Parsing as local time is adding an additional offset even specifying DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

```
var input = Console.ReadLine("Enter a time in format yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm");
var FromTime = DateTime.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

I want to ask my user for a time, in their local timezone and work with it. However it seems to be treating the time input as UTC and adding an offset to my local timezone (BST) even though I specify `AssumeLocal`:

"2017-4-1-1200" => `FromTime = {01/04/2017 13:00:00}` in the debugger.
[image]

Why is getting .Net to treat the time I type in as a local time not trivial, how am I supposed to do it with least fuss and what am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Where did you find this format? Use "2017-4-1 12:00".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the format of the input string.

This will give you a UTC time:

```
var input = "2017-12-31-1200";
var fromTime = DateTime.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Result: {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", fromTime));
//Outputs 2017-12-31 05:00:00 for me
```

This will give you the local time (notice I changed the hypen to a space and changed "1200" to "12:00"):

```
var input = "2017-12-31 12:00";
var fromTime = DateTime.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Result: {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", fromTime));
//outputs 2017-12-31 12:00
```

I am not sure what format includes a hyphen separating the date and time and a time without a colon.  But apparently .NET interprets this as a UTC date/time expression.

You can get around this by using `ParseExact`:

```
string input = "2017-12-31-1200";
var fromTime = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Result: {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", fromTime));
//outputs 2017-12-31 12:00:00
```